# What should I use instead of the deprecated `Vertex#rxExecuteBlocking`, starting with Vert.x 4.5?

Tags: java, rx-java, vert.x

Starting with **Vert.x 4.5.0**, `Vertx#rxExecuteBlocking` (and the signatures of `executeBlocking` that return a `Maybe`) [are deprecated](https://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/deprecated-list.html).

How should I go from a **Vert.x `Future`** (with `Vertx#executeBlocking`) to an **RxJava `Maybe`** (or an `Observable`)?

Comment: There should be an [alternative method](https://github.com/eclipse-vertx/vert.x/blob/master/src/main/java/io/vertx/core/Vertx.java#L587) generated, that use a `Callable` param. If it's not present, it's a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### This isn't the answer I'm looking for, but is an answer nonetheless

I imagine that there must somewhere be a function that turns a `Future` to a `Maybe` or even an `Observable` straight away. That's what I'm looking for!

---

### The option I figured out

Here's an option, although I'm not sure it is the most appropriate one:

Where you would get a Vert.x `Future` from some computation-intensive activity (such as `Thread#sleep` ) from a method defined as follows:

```java
private static final Vertx VERTX = Vertx.vertx();

private static Future<String> compute() {
  return VERTX.executeBlocking(() -> {
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    return "Done.";
  });
}
```

You could get a `Maybe` like so:

```java
final Maybe<String> maybe = MaybeHelper
  .toMaybe(handler -> compute().onComplete(handler));
```

---

As an additional note, I'd like to point out that the `Maybe`-to-`Observable` conversion seems to be trivially resolved using `Maybe#toObservable`, thus allowing the following way to obtain an `Observable` out of `Vertx#executeBlocking`:

```java
final Observable<String> observable = MaybeHelper
  .toMaybe(handler -> compute().onComplete(handler))
  .toObservable();
```

---

Here's a small helper class that may assist you in converting a **Vert.x `Future`** to an **RxJava `Observable`** (which I think should exist in the `vertx-rx-java3` package but I can't locate):

```java
import io.reactivex.rxjava3.core.Observable;
import io.vertx.core.Future;
import io.vertx.rxjava3.MaybeHelper;

public class Observables {

  public static <T> Observable<T> from(final Future<T> future) {
    return MaybeHelper.<T>toMaybe(future::onComplete).toObservable();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a [bug](https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-rx/issues/302) that will be fixed in Vert.x 4.5.1